# Set Up Data Extraction Filters across all tabs of a R shiny App

Tags: r, shiny

I have an R shiny app with three tabs. Each tab has a `tableOutput`. Additionally the first tab has 2 `SelectInput` filters and an `actionButton`. This is how the app works. The user selects the filters and clicks the button in the first tab, then tables will get generated across all three tabs. The table generation logic across all three tabs uses the user selection as Input. Now for user convenience I want to have these filters across all tabs. So in what ever tab the user wants to execute logic, tables should get updated across all tabs and when user switches from one tab to another, the filters should display same user selections. How can I do it without repeating the code for UI and server.